# Add security policy to ELB config in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm configering an Elastic Loadbalancer through `.ebextensions`:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: redirect
          RedirectConfig:
            Protocol: HTTPS
            Port: '443'
            Host: '#{host}'
            Path: '/#{path}'
            Query: '#{query}'
            StatusCode: HTTP_301
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListenerHTTPS:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxx
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn:
            Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
```

I've manually changed the security policy of the load balancer to: ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-Res-2020-10

I would love to add the policy to the `.config` file but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2-listener-default) of all the Elastic Beanstalk configuration options, if you were using the standard `.ebextensions` settings, you would set the `SSLPolicy` setting in either the `aws:elbv2:listener:default` namespace or the `aws:elbv2:listener:listener_port` namespace.

It looks like instead of using the standard settings, you are instead providing custom CloudFormation resource definitions. In that case you need to set the `SslPolicy` property on the SSL listener you have defined, as [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener.html).